# Specific bar_index Price ahead

Tags: pine-script

When we use `bar_index[1]` we mean 1 bar ago, is there a way of saying 10 bars after event?

Example: plot an "X" 10 bars AFTER the highest high in the January.

Also if I know the bar_index is it possible to get the `high` at `bar_index 1550`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ta.valuewhen()` function for both these cases.

```
//`bar_index` of the last bar where the `event` was 10 bars ago.    
ta.valuewhen(event[10], bar_index, 0)
    
// `high` of the bar where `bar_index == 1550` was true.
ta.valuewhen(bar_index == 1550, high, 0)

// Alternative method: save value of `high` into a variable when the condition is true
var float h = na
if bar_index == 1550
    h := high
```